# Any idea why this 'not an answer' flag was declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I've checked multiple 'identical' question, but did not directly find one that referred to a similar kind of answer than [the one I flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500087/cant-retreive-selected-data-on-dynamic-pselectonemenu/32500793#32500793) as 'not an answer'. I fail to see why my flag was declined. If this is a real answer, 30% of my comments would be answers but not directly have helped anyone. Please enlighten me.

Comment: That answer contains *try adding xxx*, which, under our current "consensus", makes it a valid attempt at answering I'm afraid. You would have better luck with a custom "should be a comment" flag rather than a NAA flag in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes it a little more clear, although in some cases simiilar flags were accepted. But I'll try to flag it as 'should be a comment'  (if available, since I think I do not always see that option).

Comment: @Kukeltje it does not exist.  It's a _custom_ flag.  These go straight to the mods.  Only use them for actions that normal users can accomplish (such as converting to a comment), and you need to be specific on what you want to actually happen and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

> Is your ManagedBean `@ViewScoped`? Also try adding `process = "@this"  partialSubmit="true"` to `<p:ajax listener="#{managedBean.updateColorOnCar(car)}" />` and check if your color is being saved on selecting `#{car.color.id}` from menu.

Now imagine you're a moderator and this is all you see to determine if your flag should be declined or not. Keep in mind that deleting anything of value is a sin.

Your own analysis of the answer is inline with mine:

> This is not an answer but a question... it contains a question mark, the word 'try' and the word 'check' in just three lines.

but based on that analysis I down vote such answers instead of flagging. It is an attempt to answer, it provides two possible solutions. I could argue the answerer might have want to write: *If your ManagedBean is `@ViewScoped` you might try...*.

The attempt to answer reasoning can be found in the (in)famous [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) that goes into a lengthy discussion and background on when to use the NAA flag. And as Shog9 has some influence on the moderators you can be sure they follow the advice on how to handle those flags.

Comment: _"It is an attempt to answer, it provides two possible solutions. I could argue the answerer might have want to write: If your ManagedBean is @ViewScoped you might try...."_ In 95% of the cases in the JSF/PrimeFaces tagged questions this is unfortunately not the case. Users answering like this are either new users without enough rep to comment or users that just take a (usually wrong) wild guess and format the answer like this since they did not try themselves (would have failed). Unfortunately, SO users I see in the these tags) more and more seem to be like 'script-kiddies' or plain out lazy.

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar in that tag at all and if you assume the moderator handling your tag is probably making the same mistake.  Down vote and find a 20K-er that want to delete vote such answers give a better success rate.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is good clearification.